# TensorFlow optimizer for linear system

Tags: tensorflow, optimization, noise

I have a dataset with colliding labels (class noise). It has only two (integer) features, one of which is fairly correlated with the output. I am trying to get TensorFlow to optimize the coefficients but it performs so poorly, I think the accuracy is wrong or this is somehow something that tf can't really do. I dumbed the dataset down to a subset (622 samples out of 23k) where there is no class noise + made the first feature a simple multipe of the labels. Here's the dumbed down dataset:

f1,f2,label
1,1,47
10,82,140
10,85,140
10,88,140
10,89,148
10,90,140
10,91,149
10,93,140
10,95,140
21,92,26
21,94,26
21,98,26
22,91,148
22,95,148
22,96,148
22,97,148
22,98,148
23,91,3
23,92,3
23,93,3
23,96,3
24,81,29
24,82,29
24,84,29
24,86,29
24,88,29
24,89,29
24,90,29
24,91,29
24,92,29
24,94,29
24,96,29
38,89,3
38,90,3
38,91,3
38,92,3
38,94,3
38,95,3
38,96,3
38,97,3
38,98,5
38,99,5
40,96,1
40,98,1
40,99,1
47,86,126
47,94,126
47,98,126
47,99,126
48,77,31
48,78,31
48,79,31
48,81,31
48,82,31
48,85,31
48,86,31
48,89,31
48,90,31
49,92,3
49,95,3
49,96,3
49,98,3
50,96,116
51,97,156
52,91,164
52,93,164
52,94,164
53,91,26
53,93,26
54,96,7
54,98,7
54,99,7
60,82,163
60,84,163
60,85,163
60,86,163
60,88,163
60,89,163
60,91,163
60,93,163
60,95,163
61,82,159
61,85,159
61,86,159
61,87,159
61,89,159
63,98,6
64,94,141
64,95,141
64,96,141
64,97,141
64,98,141
64,99,141
65,83,165
65,84,165
65,85,165
65,86,165
65,92,165
66,87,159
66,88,159
66,91,159
66,92,159
66,93,159
66,94,159
66,96,159
66,99,159
67,85,157
67,89,157
67,90,157
67,92,157
67,95,157
67,97,157
69,97,26
71,88,161
71,90,161
71,91,161
73,98,141
73,99,141
74,95,15
74,98,15
75,99,74
76,88,152
76,89,152
76,93,152
77,96,90
77,98,90
78,93,141
78,94,141
78,95,141
78,96,141
78,97,141
78,98,141
78,99,141
79,99,3
80,82,98
80,83,98
80,86,98
81,94,71
81,95,71
81,96,71
81,99,71
82,91,72
82,92,72
82,94,72
82,97,72
82,99,72
83,85,20
83,88,20
83,89,20
83,91,20
83,92,20
83,94,20
85,96,85
85,97,85
85,98,85
86,98,95
87,89,98
87,91,98
87,92,98
87,93,98
87,94,98
87,95,98
87,96,98
89,84,98
89,85,98
89,87,98
89,89,98
89,90,98
89,91,98
89,92,98
89,93,98
89,94,98
89,96,98
89,97,98
89,99,98
97,96,92
97,98,92
97,99,92
98,79,64
98,80,64
98,81,64
98,82,64
98,83,64
98,86,64
98,87,64
98,88,64
98,89,64
98,90,64
98,91,64
98,92,64
98,93,64
98,94,64
98,95,64
98,96,64
98,97,64
98,98,64
103,82,3
103,83,26
103,85,26
103,88,26
103,89,26
103,92,26
103,94,26
122,91,15
122,92,15
122,93,15
125,84,112
125,85,112
125,86,112
125,88,125
125,90,112
125,91,112
125,93,112
125,94,112
125,95,112
125,96,125
125,98,112
127,92,15
127,94,15
127,95,15
127,98,15
129,90,139
129,91,139
129,92,139
129,93,139
129,95,139
129,96,139
130,75,143
130,76,143
130,78,142
130,79,142
130,80,143
130,81,142
130,82,143
130,83,141
130,84,141
130,85,141
130,86,141
130,87,141
130,88,141
130,89,141
130,90,141
130,91,141
130,92,141
130,93,141
130,94,141
130,95,141
130,96,145
130,97,145
132,81,62
132,84,62
132,89,62
132,90,62
132,94,62
136,90,130
136,91,130
136,92,130
144,88,19
144,93,19
144,94,19
144,97,19
147,95,140
147,96,140
147,97,140
147,99,140
149,93,151
149,95,151
149,96,151
149,97,151
149,98,151
152,83,147
152,86,147
152,87,147
152,89,147
152,90,147
152,91,147
152,93,147
152,95,147
156,89,43
156,94,45
156,95,45
165,99,6
167,85,97
167,86,97
167,90,97
167,91,97
167,92,97
167,93,97
167,96,97
169,89,10
169,90,10
169,91,10
169,93,10
169,95,10
170,85,152
170,86,152
170,87,152
170,89,152
170,90,152
170,91,152
170,92,152
170,93,152
170,94,152
170,95,152
170,96,152
170,97,152
171,93,3
171,94,3
171,96,3
171,97,3
171,98,3
172,84,73
172,85,73
172,92,73
172,95,73
172,99,73
173,82,76
173,83,76
173,84,76
173,85,76
173,87,76
173,88,76
173,89,76
173,90,76
173,93,76
174,85,107
174,87,107
174,88,107
174,90,107
175,91,15
175,92,15
175,93,15
175,96,33
175,97,33
176,89,112
176,90,112
176,91,112
176,92,112
176,94,112
176,95,112
176,96,112
176,97,112
177,95,26
177,97,26
177,98,26
178,82,6
178,84,6
178,85,6
178,86,6
178,87,6
178,88,6
178,89,6
178,90,6
178,95,6
191,94,141
191,95,141
191,96,141
191,97,141
191,98,141
191,99,141
192,85,153
192,86,153
192,88,153
192,89,153
192,92,153
193,91,97
193,92,97
193,93,97
193,95,97
193,96,97
193,97,97
195,77,95
195,85,95
195,86,95
195,87,95
195,88,95
196,90,111
196,91,111
196,94,111
196,95,111
196,96,111
196,97,111
196,98,111
196,99,111
199,71,160
199,73,160
199,74,160
199,75,160
199,79,160
199,81,160
199,82,160
199,83,160
199,84,160
199,86,160
200,73,32
200,77,32
200,83,32
200,84,32
200,86,32
200,88,32
204,93,150
204,94,150
204,95,150
204,96,150
204,98,150
206,90,94
206,91,94
206,93,94
206,94,94
206,97,94
206,99,94
208,86,96
208,87,96
208,88,96
208,89,96
208,90,96
208,91,96
208,92,96
208,93,96
208,95,96
208,96,96
221,95,60
221,98,60
221,99,60
226,89,111
226,91,111
226,92,111
226,93,111
226,94,111
226,95,111
226,96,111
226,99,111
227,89,128
227,90,128
227,91,128
227,95,128
227,96,128
227,97,128
227,98,128
229,94,3
229,95,3
229,96,3
229,97,3
229,98,3
229,99,3
230,90,147
230,91,147
230,92,147
230,95,147
231,98,3
231,99,3
234,90,0
234,94,0
234,95,0
234,96,0
234,97,0
234,98,0
235,79,0
235,81,0
235,82,0
235,83,0
235,84,0
237,83,127
237,84,127
237,85,127
237,87,127
237,88,127
237,89,127
237,90,127
237,93,127
237,95,127
238,83,128
238,85,128
238,87,128
238,89,128
238,92,128
238,93,128
238,94,128
238,95,128
238,96,128
241,90,86
241,92,86
241,93,86
241,95,86
245,95,141
245,96,141
245,97,141
245,98,141
245,99,141
246,90,107
246,91,107
246,94,107
246,96,107
246,98,107
248,80,29
248,84,29
248,85,29
248,90,29
248,93,29
248,94,29
248,95,29
248,96,29
248,97,29
248,99,29
249,94,3
249,99,3
257,85,140
257,86,140
257,87,140
257,92,140
257,93,140
258,96,64
258,97,64
258,98,64
258,99,64
262,84,110
262,85,110
262,91,110
262,93,110
262,95,110
262,97,110
275,96,69
275,97,69
276,97,70
276,98,70
276,99,70
277,94,141
277,95,141
277,96,141
277,97,141
277,98,141
277,99,141
279,85,20
279,86,20
279,89,20
279,90,20
279,91,20
279,92,20
279,94,20
279,97,20
280,97,141
280,98,141
281,95,27
281,96,27
281,97,27
283,82,4
283,84,4
283,85,4
283,86,4
283,88,4
283,90,4
283,91,4
283,92,4
283,95,4
283,96,4
283,97,4
284,80,6
284,81,6
284,82,6
284,83,6
284,84,6
284,85,6
284,86,6
284,90,6
284,91,6
284,94,6
286,99,108
290,67,81
290,68,81
290,70,81
290,80,81
292,91,4
292,94,4
292,95,4
293,91,148
293,92,148
293,93,148
293,94,148
293,95,148
293,96,148
293,97,148
294,84,126
294,85,126
294,90,126
294,92,126
295,66,29
295,68,29
295,69,29
295,72,29
295,74,29
295,75,29
295,80,29
314,73,126
314,74,126
314,75,126
314,76,126
314,77,126
314,79,126
314,80,126
314,81,126
314,82,126
314,83,126
314,84,126
314,85,126
314,87,126
314,88,126
314,89,126
314,90,126
316,96,152
316,97,152
316,98,152
317,80,49
317,82,49
317,86,49
318,88,152
318,89,152
318,91,152
318,92,155
318,93,152
318,94,152
318,95,152

I use a shallow network:

```
labels = list(df['label'].unique())
df['One-hot'] = df['label'].map(lambda x: np.eye(len(labels))[labels.index(x)] )
shuffled = df.sample(frac=1)
trainingSet = shuffled[0:len(shuffled)-120]
testSet = shuffled[len(shuffled)-120:]
train = trainingSet.sample(500)

inp = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 2])
f1 = tf.ones([1, 74])
f2 = tf.zeros([1, 74])#even start with telling f2 is not useful
f12 = tf.concat([f1, f2],0)
weights = tf.Variable(f12)
bias = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([74]))

y = tf.matmul(inp, weights) + bias
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 74])
cross_entropy = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=y, labels=y_)
cost = tf.reduce_mean(cross_entropy)

global_step = tf.Variable(0, trainable=False)
starter_learning_rate = 0.01
train_step = tf.train.ProximalAdagradOptimizer(starter_learning_rate).minimize(cross_entropy)

correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y,1), tf.argmax(y_,1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, "float"))

pb = tf.Print(bias, [bias], 'pb')
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess = tf.Session()
saver = tf.train.Saver()
sess.run(init)

minimum = 1000000
min_acc = [0, 0.36]
keys = [0,1]
for i in range(500000):
  sess.run(train_step, feed_dict= {
                    inp: [x for x in train[keys].values],
                     y_: [x for x in train['One-hot'].as_matrix()]})
  d = sess.run(cost, feed_dict= {
                    inp: [x for x in train[keys].values],
                     y_: [x for x in train['One-hot'].as_matrix()]})

  if(i==1):
    print(d)
    pw=  sess.run(tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES))
    print(pw)
    acc = sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={
               inp: [x for x in testSet[keys].values], 
                y_: [x for x in testSet['One-hot'].values]})
```

etc.

My question is, what is the problem here? My original dataset contains 2 features and class noise, why is that a problem? (8 nearest neighbors attains 36% correct v. 5% by tf, even a deep FCN). Is it the low number of features? The optimizer? The cost? Too few samples? How many samples is best for

> train = trainingSet.sample(500)

If you have an answer please show the steps, because I don't find tensorflow very helpful in getting closer to an answer. A slightly more difficult problem wouldn't have the labels = A*f1 consistency, if you have a solution, does it work on that too?

Comment: at least normal init of f1 improves it a little, I'll try standardizing the feats too

Comment: I'm not knowledgeable about Tensorflow, but I think it looks like your using a loss designed for binary labels (cross-entropy), when you have integer labels. I would try switching it to quadratic loss.

Comment: The labels are one-hot coded.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you're not using hidden layers. It's not a shallow neural network then, it's just logistic (softmax) regression. I wouldn't expect that to work very well, especially with the number of classes you have.

Typically people would train 1-against-all classifiers when using logistic regression, as the multi-class softmax like your using can be very unstable during optimisation. Try a single hidden layer model first, though.

Comment: Thank you Aaron. That it is unstable is definitely true, but why? All it needs to do is descend every weight to zero except for the weight between the class specific inputs and their labels. Then softmax gives the desired optimum. It seems every weight is now forcedly perturbed and then a multi input combination is sought (useful in standard situations and DL). It's possibly because with the second feature there, gradient descent needs to walk along the side of valleys. I will remove it and see again. Another possibility is that this is caused by saturation prevention.